# How can I solve?... I think it's not have problem in code

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/...filename/list1.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: you can't access a cross origin resource  unless that resource lets you ... but it never works from `file:///` protocol, you need to use `http://` or `https://` for YOUR file

Comment: or the other protocols mentioned in the error